# In Matlab, how to fast generate 'sparse random matrix', and fast multiply it with a dense vector?

Tags: matlab

I am using this function X = randsrc(250,600,[[-1,0,1];[0.5/ps,1-1/ps,0.5/ps]])) with ps=2373 It shows that 250*600 matrix is generated. Its entries only contain  -1,0 or 1. And -1,0,1 is randomly choosed according to the probability distribution 0.5/ps,1-1/ps,0.5/ps.

So that the density is about 0.00042.

The above  X is called sparse random projection matrix, see https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Ping/KDD06_rp.pdf. It can be used to compress a data vector from dimension 600 to 250 with some nice geometric properties guaranteed.

The problem is that in Matlab,  **randsrc** seems to be very slow (e.g., compared with randn(250,600)). Then, how can I fast generate the above matrix?

BTW, how can I fast calculate X*y? where y may be a dense vector.

My code is:

```
ps=2373;
tic;
X = randsrc(250,600,[[-1,0,1];[0.5/ps,1-1/ps,0.5/ps]]));
toc

a = randn(600,1);
tic;
X*a;
toc
```

Also, I have tried a same Python function http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.random_projection.SparseRandomProjection.html, it is twice faster than Matlab.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood what you meant: so you already have a code which does the work but you want to make it faster? if yes, can you please upload the code?

Comment: I don't quite understand your numbers. `1/ps` seems to be much less than `0.035`. What am I missing?

Comment: @beaker sorry, you are right. I have updated the code.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. The only thing that I can think of is to calculate the number of `1` and `-1` values and select random positions for them using `randperm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprand to generate a sparsity structure, then find to extract the rows and columns of the non-zero elements. Finally randsample will select values -1,1 with 50% probability of each:

```
ps=2373;
tic
[i,j,~] = find(sprand(250,600,1/ps))
X = sparse(i,j,randsample([-1,1],length(i),true))
toc
```

MATLAB is very fast at multiplying matrices so X*a is very fast.